# After Signing In Not Navigating to main page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i am following a tutorial from Youtube. when i go with the flow everything works fine but when i add my code it gives errors.
when user is sign in for the first time after logout it stucks to the signin page and doesnot navigate to main page. but when we close and open app again it takes user to main page. please help me with this i googled it and i asked questions in fb groups but could not found a solution.
here is my code.
from auth.dart file

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/models/user.dart';

class AuthService {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  UserModel _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? UserModel(id: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<UserModel> get user {
    return auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  Future signUp(email, password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.user.uid)
          .set({'name': email, 'email': email});
      _userFromFirebaseUser(user.user);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future signIn(email, password) async {
    try {
      User user = (await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password)) as User;

      _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

from Signin.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/screens/auth/signup.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/utilities/constants.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  SignIn({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final AuthService _authService = AuthService();
  
  
  ///variables to store email and password
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  bool _rememberMe = false;
 Widget _buildLoginBtn() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        // elevation: 5.0,
        onPressed:() 
         async => 
          {
           _authService.signIn(email, password)
          },
        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        // shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        // ),
        // color: Colors.white,
        child: Text(
          'LOGIN',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF527DAA),
            letterSpacing: 1.5,
            fontSize: 18.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? And share the code which determines what page the user is on, not this Auth class alone.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad the user is on signin page which is below auth. the problem is that the user is logged in in the terminal but the screen is not changing. it stucks to the signin page however when i re run the app it automatically takes me to the main page.

Comment: You're not telling your code to takeyou anywhere after sign in. unless that page is wrapped in a stream or future builder which monitors auth state changes, the page won't navigate.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad but it works on another file just like this. why is it so. i followed a tutorial on Youtube. and it worked fine. but when i put this code which i wrote it does not work. and why is it navigating to main page after a re run

Comment: it's navigating because auth sessions are stored for firebase. The conversion is happening in your app before the login page. Wrap it in a streambuilder, which listens to authStateChanges, and if user!=null return your homepage, otherwise, return the login page. Read the documentation, they are always updated, better than tutorials. Firebase documentation is one of the best out there honestly, I urge you as a developer to do it, it's better for your future self, get used to reading documentation.